# Summing expression involving input variables

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I am doing optimization using Pyomo library. I am trying to create an expression which involves summing expressions involving input variables.

```
x = [k*model.input[i] for i in range(3)]
return [x[i] for i in range(3)]/sum([x[i] for i in range(3)])
```

I am getting below error :

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'SumExpression'

What is the correct formulation for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your return line you have a list `[x[i] for i in range(3)]` divided by a sum `sum([x[i] for i in range(3)])`. The interpreter is telling it does not know what this division means. Are you trying to divide each entry of the list as in vector division? Then you can use:

```py
x = [k*model.input[i] for i in range(3)]
denominator = sum([x[i] for i in range(3)])
return [x[i]/denominator for i in range(3)]
```